# Swift casting Any to closure

Tags: swift, casting, closures

I'm trying to cast a function stocked as Any in a Dictionary.
The cast fails, and I don't really understand why. I tried to search for similar examples with no luck.

```
fileprivate let array: [[String:Any]] = [
    [
      "title": "my title",
      "image": "image url",
      "callback": callback
    ]
]

func callback() {
    print("called")
}

if let callback = array[0]["callback"] as? () -> Void {
    callback()
}
```

Any help is welcome!
Cheers

Comment: What’s the alert message?

Comment: Your code works fine in a standalone Swift file (if you swap `array` and `callback`, otherwise it doesn't build).

Comment: Debug callback object and tell us what you get

Comment: There is no alert message, the ```if let callback = array[0]["callback"] as? () -> Void``` just always fails and the callback is never called.
When I try to print the content of the array with po, I get "callback": (function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have commented, your code works as posted in a Playground, provided you move the declaration of the `callback` function above the declaration of the array.  However, I could see a possible issue if you are declaring `array` and `callback` as instance members inside a struct or class, e.g.:

```
class MyClass {
  fileprivate let array: [[String:Any]] = [
    [
      "title": "my title",
      "image": "image url",
      "callback": callback
    ]
  ]

  func callback() {
    print("called")
  }
}
```

In this case, the method `callback` doesn't have the type you would expect (`()->Void`).  Rather, since it is an instance method, it needs to know what `self` is in order to potentially reference it (because it's an instance method).  So the type of `callback` in this case is actually `(MyClass) -> () -> Void`, meaning, if you call `callback` with an instance of `MyClass` to represent `self`, it will return a function of the type you are expecting: `()->Void`.

If this is what you are running into, you need to make sure to reference the `callback` method as `self.callback` when creating the array in order to get the version of the method already installed with `self`.

And in order to reference `self` in a property declaration, you have to make it lazy. So in the example above, this would work as expected:

```
class MyClass {
  fileprivate lazy var array: [[String:Any]] = {
    [
      [
        "title": "my title",
        "image": "image url",
        "callback": self.callback
      ]
    ]
  }()

  func callback() {
    print("called")
  }
}
```

Comment: That was the problem, my array and callback were declared as instance members of my class. Thank you so much for the explanation, was really clear!